# Operations in views

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a view in which I take fields from tables and do some operations, and some operations depend on from the result the others, and in a view don't allow create a variable, How can I replace the variables in my view?

Comment: That sounds as if a view is not the right choice for your requirement. Consider using a function ora stored proc instead.

Comment: You can use a parameter table populated with filter variables and values that you can link to your existing view to filter it. Update the parameter table with the variables before running the view.

Comment: You might be able to do it with a cte or two.

Comment: tks, I group the principal subqueries that return me the values in a select with an alias like a table, then I use the result of these queries like variables  in the same view